# How to import a single method form python library and still keep the namespace?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I want to import the `random.sample()` method, but I can either import the whole library by typing `import random` or lose the namespace by typing `from random import sample`.

How can I just import the single method but a able to call it with `random.sample()`? Is there a elegant way to do it?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Good question, well I have another function called sample(), and I know I can just type "import sample as sample2" or rename my function, just wanted to know if there is a way to do it like this, seemed cleaner to me.